# Google Apps Script - Trying to find a Google Sheet by name on Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, spreadsheet, gmail-addons

I'm trying to create a sheet that will work like a database for some data from Gmail (my sidebar works only on Gmail).

But, before I create a new google sheet for that, I have to look if the sheet already exists. If it does, I want to save the data to the existing sheet.

How can I do that?

GetContextualAddOn.gs

```
var MESSAGE;
//Returns the sidebar with his cards
function getContextualAddOn(event) {
  MESSAGE = getCurrentMessage(event);
  var prefills = [getTitle(MESSAGE),
                  getBody(MESSAGE)];
  var card = createExpensesCard(prefills);

  return [card.build()];
}

//Get the current message opened
function getCurrentMessage(event) {
  var accessToken = event.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  var messageId = event.messageMetadata.messageId;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  return GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
}
```

Cards.gs

```
var FIELDNAMES = ['Título', 'Mensagem', 'URL da Planilha'];

/**
 * Creates the main card users see with form inputs to log expense.
 * Form can be prefilled with values.
 *
 * @param {String[]} opt_prefills Default values for each input field.
 * @param {String} opt_status Optional status displayed at top of card.
 * @returns {Card}
 */
function createExpensesCard(opt_prefills, opt_status) {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();

  var clearForm = CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName('clearForm')
    .setParameters({'Status': opt_status ? opt_status : ''});
  var clearAction = CardService.newCardAction()
    .setText('Clear form')
    .setOnClickAction(clearForm);
  card.addCardAction(clearAction);

  if (opt_status) {
    if (opt_status.indexOf('Error: ') == 0) {
      opt_status = '<font color=\'#FF0000\'>' + opt_status + '</font>';
    } else {
      opt_status = '<font color=\'#1dd11d\'>' + opt_status + '</font>';
    }
    var statusSection = CardService.newCardSection();
    statusSection.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph()
      .setText('<b>' + opt_status + '</b>'));
    card.addSection(statusSection);
  }

  var formSection = createFormSection(CardService.newCardSection(),FIELDNAMES, opt_prefills);
var newSheetSection = CardService.newCardSection();
var sheetName = CardService.newTextInput()
  .setFieldName('Sheet Name')
  .setTitle('Nome da planilha');
var createSheet = CardService.newAction()
  .setFunctionName('createSheet');
var newSheetButton = CardService.newTextButton()
  .setText('Nova planílha')
  .setOnClickAction(createSheet);
newSheetSection.addWidget(sheetName);
newSheetSection.addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(newSheetButton));

card.addSection(newSheetSection);
  card.addSection(formSection);

  return card;
}


function createFormSection(section, inputNames, opt_prefills) {
  for (var i = 0; i < inputNames.length; i++) {
    var widget = CardService.newTextInput()
      .setFieldName(inputNames[i])
      .setTitle(inputNames[i]);
    if (opt_prefills && opt_prefills[i]) {
      widget.setValue(opt_prefills[i]);
    }
    section.addWidget(widget);
  }

  var submitForm = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('submitForm');
  var submitButton = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Submit')
    .setOnClickAction(submitForm);

  section.addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(submitButton));

  return section;
}





/**
 * Logs form inputs into a spreadsheet given by URL from form.
 * Then displays edit card.
 *
 * @param {Event} e An event object containing form inputs and parameters.
 * @returns {Card}
 */
function submitForm(e) {
  try {
  var res = e['formInput'];
    FIELDNAMES.forEach(function(fieldName) {
      if (! res[fieldName]) {
        throw 'Formulário incompleto';
      }
    });
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp
      .openByUrl((res['URL da Planilha']))
      .getActiveSheet();
    sheet.appendRow(objToArray(res, FIELDNAMES.slice(0, FIELDNAMES.length - 1)));
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty('SPREADSHEET_URL', res['URL da Planilha']);
    return createExpensesCard(null, 'Cobrança inserida com sucesso!').build();
  }
  catch (err) {
    if (err == 'Exception: Invalid argument: url') {
      err = 'URL Inválido';
      res['Spreadsheet URL'] = null;
    }
    return createExpensesCard(objToArray(res, FIELDNAMES), 'Erro: ' + err).build();
  }
}

/**
 * Returns an array corresponding to the given object and desired ordering of keys.
 *
 * @param {Object} obj Object whose values will be returned as an array.
 * @param {String[]} keys An array of key names in the desired order.
 * @returns {Object[]}
 */
function objToArray(obj, keys) {
  return keys.map(function(key) {
    return obj[key];
  });
}

/**
 * Recreates the main card without prefilled data.
 *
 * @param {Event} e An event object containing form inputs and parameters.
 * @returns {Card}
 */
function clearForm(e) {
  createSheet(e);
  return createExpensesCard(null, e['parameters']['Status']).build();
}

 function  ifExists() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts = ss.getSheets();
  for(let sheet of shts) {
    if(sheet.getName() == 'DBQuiteOften') {
      var retorno = [true,sheet];
      return retorno;
    }
  }
  var retorno = [false,];
  return retorno;
}


function createSheet(e) {
  try{
  var res = e['formInput'];
  var sheetName = res['Sheet Name'] ? res['Sheet Name'] : 'DBQuiteOften';
  var exist = ifExists();
 if(!exist[0]){
  newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheetName);
  newSpreadsheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  newSpreadsheet
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(1, 1, 1, FIELDNAMES.length - 1)
    .setValues([FIELDNAMES.slice(0, FIELDNAMES.length - 1)]);
  var prefills = objToArray(res, FIELDNAMES.slice(0, FIELDNAMES.length - 1));
  prefills.push(newSpreadsheet.getUrl());
  return createExpensesCard(prefills, 'Planílha criada e inserida com nome <i>' +
                            sheetName ).build();
 }else{
   var prefills = objToArray(res, FIELDNAMES.slice(0, FIELDNAMES.length - 1));
    prefills.push(exist[1].getUrl());
   return createExpensesCard(prefills, 'Planílha criada e inserida com nome <i>' +
                            sheetName ).build();
 }

  } catch (err) {
    if (err == 'Exception: Invalid argument: url') {
      err = 'URL Inválido';
      res['Spreadsheet URL'] = null;
    }
    return createExpensesCard(objToArray(res, FIELDNAMES), 'Erro: ' + err).build();
  }

}
```

Helpers.gs

```
/*
* Get body of the selected message
*/
function getBody(message) {
  return message.getBody();
}



function getUser(){
    // If user has themselves in their contacts, return their name

    // Prefer given name, if that's available
     var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
    return userName;

}


/**
 * Determines date the email was received.
 *
 * @param {Message} message An email message.
 * @returns {String}
 */
function getReceivedDate(message) {
  return message.getDate().toLocaleDateString();
}

/**
 * Determines title by joining sender name and message subject.
 *
 * @param {Message} message An email message.
 * @returns {String}
 */
function getTitle(message) {
  var sender = message.getFrom();
  var subject = message.getSubject();
  return sender + " | " + subject;
}

/**
 * Determines most recent spreadsheet URL.
 * Returns null if no URL was previously submitted.
 *
 * @returns {String}
 */
/**
 * Determines most recent spreadsheet URL.
 * Returns null if no URL was previously submitted.
 *
 * @returns {String}
 */
function getSheetUrl() {
  return PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('SPREADSHEET_URL');
}
```

appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "GMT",
  "oauthScopes": [
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
   "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"
],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Salvar Email",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/bookmark_white_24dp.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "getContextualAddOn"
    }],
    "primaryColor": "#00FFFF",
    "secondaryColor": "#99FFFF"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to what I need. Using the DriveApp.

```
function ifExists() {
  var title = "SheetFileName";

  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('mimeType contains "spreadsheet" and title contains "' + title + '"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var retorno = [true,file];
    return retorno;
  }
  var retorno = [false,];
  return retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function  ifExists(name) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    if(shts[i].getName()==name) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I would have done it this way:

```
function  ifExists() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts = ss.getSheets();
  for(let sheet of shts) {
    if(sheet.getName() == 'DBQuiteOften') {
      var retorno = {found:true,sheet:sheet};
      return retorno;
    }
  }
  var retorno = {found:false,sheet:''};
  return retorno;
}
```

so then this `var exist = ifExists();` would be: `var exist = ifExists().found;`

and this  `if(!exist[0])` would  be: `if(!exist.found)`

Comment: It returns me an error: Erro: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheets' of null

Comment: I'm trying to execute this into a Gmail page, looking for a Spreadsheet file into my Google Sheets. And as I understand it is finding a tab on an opened Google Sheet.

Comment: Can you share your code?  Is it a Gmail Addon or what?

Comment: Yes! https://script.google.com/a/lyncas.net/d/1BD3Om-shqdfP3R-j2zE5mJbsyfq29QcoMqAD4wGdP-3lXaJzOAgESXiK/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow links to spreadsheets off of this site.  Please post your code in your question.

Comment: I guess I don't see where the code your requested fit's into any of that.

Comment: Sorry, I posted on the main question